# Why is first divs background not showing up?

Tags: html, css

Why is the first div's background not showing up? I have tried numerous things, like positions, display,z-index etc but I'm not sure why it is not working. I need some help with this as i believe there is a simple fix. I have tried other methods to change the opacity/ add a transparency layer over it but most things don't seem to work and the div::after method makes the image opacity too dark. Thanks for any help

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
html {
    font-family: "helvetica neue", sans-serif;
}

.nav {
/*    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;*/
    text-align: right;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    z-index:100 !important;
}
.menu {
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}
.menu a {
    clear: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 10px;
    line-height: 70px;
}

.menu a:hover {
    color: blueviolet;
}

label {
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 70px;
    display: none;
    width: 26px;
    float: right;
}
#toggle {
    display: none;
}

.hero {
    background-image:url(
    
    data:image/jpeg;base64,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
    
    
    );
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
}

#hero{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index:100;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    label {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .menu {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    }
    .menu a {
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
        margin: 0;
     
    }
    #toggle:checked + .menu {
        display: block;
    }
    
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="hero"><div class="hero">
    <div class="nav">
        <h1 style="float:left; padding:0; margin:0; margin-left:40px;color:white">LOGO</h1>
        <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="#">HOME</a>
            <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
            <a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
            <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i see the background ... buildings from the sky, right ?

Comment: I wanted the other hero div ( background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);) to be shown above it so that the image is less bright.

Comment: check well your code and see which one is inside which one, then you will get your issue :) ... and you see that you simply have to switch the CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a counter-intuitive fix, but what you want to do is **remove** the **[`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)** you set on the parent `#hero` element, and instead set a negative `z-index` on the child `.hero` element. Note that you'll also need to set a **[`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)** on the child for the `z-index` to take effect. You'll want `position: relative` for this.

Also, note that setting a **[`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color)** of `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)` on your `#hero` will make the page *very* dark. I've scaled this back to `0.5` instead to showcase the blend, as can be seen in the following example:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: "helvetica neue", sans-serif;
}

.nav {
  /*    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;*/
  text-align: right;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  z-index: 100 !important;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.menu a {
  clear: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 10px;
  line-height: 70px;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: blueviolet;
}

label {
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 70px;
  display: none;
  width: 26px;
  float: right;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

.hero {
  background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,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);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  position:relative;
}

#hero {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  label {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .menu {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  }
  .menu a {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #toggle:checked+.menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tutorial</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="hero">
    <div class="hero">
      <div class="nav">
        <h1 style="float:left; padding:0; margin:0; margin-left:40px;color:white">LOGO</h1>
        <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
        <div class="menu">
          <a href="#">HOME</a>
          <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
          <a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
          <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i think the easy fix is to simply switch the CSS ;) as one is the child of the other